# Assembler Language: Error A2075 Jump destination too far: by 30 bytes

Tags: assembly, byte

What is the  best way to check and debug if jumping too far?

So I have a var `inBuffer` which contains a `BYTE` lenght of 115.
I move that into `bufSize` and try xor'ing it against a set of 3 keys to decrypt the message.
My code compiles but I am unable to to build except this part where it says I am jumping too far.

```
bufSize DWORD ?
mov eax,115
mov bufSize,eax

;-------------------------------------------------
AnalyzeBuffer PROC
;receives nothing
;returns nothing
;-------------------------------------------------
pushad          ; pushes all data in this method into a stack
mov ecx,bufSize ; loop count
mov esi,0       ; start at index 0 in translated buffer

top:
    cmp buffer[esi],20h    ; checks if character is space which is ok
    je yes

    cmp buffer[esi],2ch    ; checks if character is comma wich is okay
    je yes

    cmp buffer[esi],2eh    ; checks if character is period which is okay
    je yes

    cmp buffer[esi],41h     ; checks if character is above A in the ascii chart
    jb no

    ;the following are all unacceptable characters
    cmp buffer[esi],5bh     ;checks if character is [
    je no
    cmp buffer[esi],5ch     ; checks if character is \
    je no
    cmp buffer[esi],5dh     ;checks if character is ]
    je no
    cmp buffer[esi],5eh      ; checks if character is ^
    je no
    cmp buffer[esi],5fh     ; checks if character is _
    je no
    cmp buffer[esi],60h     ; checks if character is `
    je no
    cmp buffer[esi],7bh     ; checks if characre is {
    je no
    cmp buffer[esi],7ch     ; checks if character is |
    je no
    cmp buffer[esi],7dh     ; checks if }
    je no
    cmp buffer[esi],7eh     ; checks if ~
    je no
    cmp buffer[esi],7fh     ; checks if 
    je no



    yes:
        inc esi             ; going to next character
        loop top
        ;getting to this step means these keys worked for all characters in buffer

        mov edx,OFFSET goodMsg
        call WriteString
        call DisplayAllKeys ; shows 3 keys used
        call Crlf
        call Crlf
        mov edx,OFFSET buffer   ; displays decrypted message
        call WriteString
        call Crlf
        call Crlf

    no:
    ;the current character wasnt good so trying next key
    popad
    ret

AnalyzeBuffer ENDP
```

Comment: Usually when this happens, you switch the jump instruction to jump in the opposite case and treat the other case immedietly after the jump instruction. I'm not sure that this will work in your case, seeing that you have a lot of jumps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next time you should tell which line is causing the error. I am guessing it is the `loop` instruction, because that only exists with a 8 bit offset. Due to optimization reasons, it's it's recommended to avoid using it anyway, and that will solve your jump range problem too. So, just replace it with a `dec ecx; jnz top`.

You could also optimize your checks, but that's another story.

Comment: line 133 which is `loop top` so it could be `inc esi` which could be the problem?

Comment: `loop` is the problem, as I said.